# I have Type-D Polish national Visa. Under what circumstances will it be cancelled?

Tags: visa, schengen, poland

I have come to Poland to study in a university. I have a Type-D National Visa.

I am actually planning to move to a university any other country in Schengen. If I cancel my admission (this is needed to get back my tuition money that I have already paid) in the polish university before I get the acceptance letter from my target university, will I be able to stay in Poland until I get acceptance?

will I be staying with a threat of stripping my visa off?

What is the rule?

Comment: Do you have temporary residence card or just a visa?

Comment: @Karlson, only visa.

Comment: From what I can gather you will always be under the threat of revocation of the visa but furthermore you will need to check whether or not you will be able to obtain a National visa to another country in Schengen in Poland.  Since you will need to be able to show that you're residing in Poland to obtain one.  Any further documentation will need to be reviewed on the Act on Foreigners which went into effect on May 1, 2014 but I am not fluent in Polish to review it's provisions.

Comment: @Karlson, so, if I keep my admission, there would be no/little problem getting visa of another country in schengen? Or, what?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose was to study in Poland, and your application had to be supported by a letter of acceptance from a university. Once you withdraw, you change the conditions of the visa. The university may certainly notify the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.msz.gov.pl/en/travel_to_poland/visa/), which will determine if, and for how long, you may remain.

While you may be able visit other Schengen Area countries, the National D visa allows you to reside in the country which issued it; it does not entitle you to take up residence in another EU country and enroll in a university there.